# can't remove duplication after integrating data.frame objects

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have vector in multiple data.frame objects where order of vector in each is different. However, I intend to combine data.frame objects without duplication. I tried most common approach to get rid of duplication while to get combined data.frame objects. But I still can't remove duplication after integrating my data.frame objects. Does anyone know any useful trick of doing this manipulation ? How can I get rid of duplication ? Any idea ? Thanks in advance

mini example:

```
hola <- data.frame(
  foo = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  bar = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,7,0,8),
  cat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,7,8,10)
)

bleh <- data.frame(
  bar = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  foo = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,0),
  cat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,13,14)
)

noh <- data.frame(
  cat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  foo = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,0,10),
  bar = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,8)
)
```

I tried this approach possibly achieve my expected output :

```
idx <- names(hola)
bleh <- bleh[idx]
noh <- noh[idx]

res <- mapply(function(x,y,z) 
  unique(rbind(x,y,z)), hola, bleh, noh)
```

but can't remove duplication, output was not clean.

This is my desired output :

```
output <- data.frame(
  foo = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9,11,0,0),
  bar = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,7,8,0,9,0,10),
  cat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,7,10,8,13,9,14)
)
```

I can't remove duplication with my approach ? Can anyone point me how to make this happen easily ?

Comment: You need `unique(res)`

Comment: Doesn't just `unique(rbind(hola, bleh, noh))` work for you (forget the re-indexing and mapply, it's not necessary)

Comment: @akrun: Thanks again, it works.